# Automatically enable button after playing music

Tags: java

I'm making a demo to play WAV file and stuck with this. When I begin to play the music, I disable the btnPlay. Now I want when the music finish playing, the btnPlay must be enable automatically. But I can't do this. I can get the file duration in microsecond but I don't know what to do next. Here is the code.

```
public void playmusic(){
    try{
        btnClose.setEnabled(true);
        btnShuffle.setEnabled(true);
        btnRepeat.setEnabled(true);
        btnPause.setEnabled(true);
        btnStop.setEnabled(true);
        btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
        if(isPausing==false){
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(f);
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(ais);
            clip.start();
        }
        else{
            isPausing=false;
            clip.start();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
}
```

Could you give me a solution for this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Offtopic: `catch(Exception ex){}` will eventually summon dragons and demons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a [LineListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/LineListener.html) to the clip and re-enable the button when the [LineEvent.Type Stop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/LineEvent.Type.html#STOP) fires.

You can find more information on the Line interface [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Line.html). The code might look something like this:

```
LineListener listener = new LineListener() {
        public void update(LineEvent event) {
        if (event.getType() == Type.STOP) {
          btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
        }        
        }
    };
clip.addLineListener(listener);
```